# how to do predictions from cox survival model with time varying coefficients

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have built a survival cox-model, which includes a `covariate * time` interaction (non-proportionality detected).
I am now wondering how could I most easily get survival predictions from my model.

My model was specified:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(event_time_mod, event_indicator_mod) ~ Sex + 
    ageC + HHcat_alt + Main_Branch + Acute_seizure + TreatmentType_binary + 
    ICH + IVH_dummy + IVH_dummy:log(event_time_mod)
```

And now I was hoping to get a prediction using `survfit` and providing `new.data` for the combination of variables I am doing the predictions:

```
survfit(cox, new.data=new)
```

Now as I have `event_time_mod` in the right-hand side in my model I need to specify it in the new data frame passed on to `survfit`. This `event_time` would need to be set at individual times of the predictions. Is there an easy way to specify `event_time_mod` to be the correct time to  `survfit`?
Or are there any other options for achieving predictions from my model?

Of course I could create as many rows in the new data frame as there are distinct times in the predictions and setting to `event_time_mod` to correct values but it feels really cumbersome and I thought that there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

You have done what is refereed to as

> An obvious but incorrect approach ...

as stated in [Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Model](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) vignette in version 2.41-3 of the R `survival` package. Instead, you should use the *time-transform functionality*, i.e., the `tt` function as stated in the same vignette. The code would be something similar to the example in the vignette

```
> library(survival)
> vfit3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno),
+                data=veteran,
+                tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t+20))
> 
> vfit3
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + prior + karno + tt(karno), 
    data = veteran, tt = function(x, t, ...) x * log(t + 20))

              coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
trt        0.01648   1.01661  0.19071  0.09  0.9311
prior     -0.00932   0.99073  0.02030 -0.46  0.6462
karno     -0.12466   0.88279  0.02879 -4.33 1.5e-05
tt(karno)  0.02131   1.02154  0.00661  3.23  0.0013

Likelihood ratio test=53.8  on 4 df, p=5.7e-11
n= 137, number of events= 128
```

The `survfit` though does not work when you have a `tt` term

```
> survfit(vfit3, veteran[1, ])
Error in survfit.coxph(vfit3, veteran[1, ]) : 
  The survfit function can not yet process coxph models with a tt term
```

However, you can easily get out the `terms`, linear predictor or mean response with `predict`. Further, you can create the term over time for the `tt` term using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31316057/5861244).