# Plotting estimated HR from coxph object with time-dependent coefficient and splines

Tags: r, spline, cox-regression

I want to plot the estimated hazard ratio as a function of time in the case of a `coxph` model with a time-dependent coefficient that is based on a spline term. I created the time-dependent coefficient using function `tt`, analogous to this example that comes straight from `?coxph`:

```
# Fit a time transform model using current age
cox = coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + tt(age), data=lung,
     tt=function(x,t,...) pspline(x + t/365.25))
```

Calling `survfit(cox)` results in an error that `survfit` does not understand models with a `tt` term ([as described in 2011 by Terry Therneau](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/117f073p9c/r-plotting-survival-curves-from-a-cox-model-with-time-dependent-covariates)).

You can extract the linear predictor using `cox$linear.predictors`, but I would need to somehow extract ages and less trivially, times to go with each. Because `tt` splits the dataset on event times, I can't just match up the columns of the input dataframe with the `coxph` output. Additionally, I really would like to plot the estimated function itself, *not* just the predictions for the observed data points.

There is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385509/how-to-plot-a-cox-hazard-model-with-splines) involving splines here, but it does not involve `tt`.

## Edit (7/7)

I'm still stuck on this. I've been looking in depth at this object:

```
spline.obj = pspline(lung$age)
str(spline.obj)

# something that looks very useful, but I am not sure what it is
# cbase appears to be the cardinal knots
attr(spline.obj, "printfun")

function (coef, var, var2, df, history, cbase = c(43.3, 47.6, 
51.9, 56.2, 60.5, 64.8, 69.1, 73.4, 77.7, 82, 86.3, 90.6)) 
{
    test1 <- coxph.wtest(var, coef)$test
    xmat <- cbind(1, cbase)
    xsig <- coxph.wtest(var, xmat)$solve
    cmat <- coxph.wtest(t(xmat) %*% xsig, t(xsig))$solve[2, ]
    linear <- sum(cmat * coef)
    lvar1 <- c(cmat %*% var %*% cmat)
    lvar2 <- c(cmat %*% var2 %*% cmat)
    test2 <- linear^2/lvar1
    cmat <- rbind(c(linear, sqrt(lvar1), sqrt(lvar2), test2, 
        1, 1 - pchisq(test2, 1)), c(NA, NA, NA, test1 - test2, 
        df - 1, 1 - pchisq(test1 - test2, max(0.5, df - 1))))
    dimnames(cmat) <- list(c("linear", "nonlin"), NULL)
    nn <- nrow(history$thetas)
    if (length(nn)) 
        theta <- history$thetas[nn, 1]
    else theta <- history$theta
    list(coef = cmat, history = paste("Theta=", format(theta)))
}
```

So, I have the knots, but I am still not sure how to combine the `coxph` coefficients with the knots in order to actually plot the function. Any leads much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can tell the lung dataset has only a single row for each patient. You would need to expand the dataset so that there were multiple lines of data with a `t`-vector.

Comment: So I would have to basically recreate what `tt` is doing under the hood? I don't believe there is a way to make `tt` return the long-form dataset...

Comment: Also, if I do that, I'll still be stuck with plotting just the predictions for the observed data point, right?

Comment: If you are getting an error with your current efforts then why are you acting annoyed at my efforts to develop a different strategy? As far as I can tell you do not have a time-dependent set of date-points. If you want an accelerated-time regression solution then you should "step up to the plate" and say so.

Comment: I wasn't annoyed at all, actually. I was asking clarifying questions. You're right that I don't have time-dependent date-points, and while the AFT model idea makes a lot of sense, one of my goals here is to directly compare a Cox model with splines to one without.

Comment: Not yet sure what you are trying to achieve, but have you read: "Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Model" by Terry Therneau and  Cindy Crowson; June 11, 2015. You would need to capture the coefficients from the pspline object and build it up. I'll post  results that can be used for that purpose:

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to plot the fitted HR for age as a function of time. I did read that document, but am still confused. I've posted a more detailed edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need can be generated by generating an input matrix using `pspline` and matrix-multiplying this by the relevant coefficients from the `coxph` output. To get the HR, you then need to take the exponent.

i.e.

```
output <- data.frame(Age = seq(min(lung$age) + min(lung$time) / 365.25,
                               max(lung$age + lung$time / 365.25),
                               0.01))
output$HR <- exp(pspline(output$Age) %*% cox$coefficients[-1] -
                 sum(cox$means[-1] * cox$coefficients[-1]))
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(output, aes(x = Age, y = HR)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot of HR vs age]

Note the age here is the age at the time of interest (i.e. the sum of the baseline age and the elapsed time since study entry). It has to use the range specified to match with the parameters in the original model. It could also be calculated using the `x` output from using `x = TRUE` as shown:

```
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog + tt(age), data=lung,
             tt=function(x,t,...) pspline(x + t/365.25), x = TRUE)
index <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(rownames(cox$x), "\\."), "[", 1)))
ages <- lung$age[index]
output2 <- data.frame(Age = ages + cox$y[, 1] / 365.25,
                      HR = exp(cox$x[, -1] %*% cox$coefficients[-1] -
                               sum(cox$means[-1] * cox$coefficients[-1])))
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks! I will probably be using a plot based on this approach for a paper in progress and would be happy to acknowledge you, if you'd like.

Comment: @half-pass very happy for you to acknowledge me. I've just been thinking over this a bit more (and looking at the code of `survival:::coxpenal.fit`) and have realised I should have subtracted the sum of the `means * coefficients` from log(HR). I've edited the code above to reflect this. The shape of the graph is identical, but the numbers on the y axis shift. It makes more sense as well that the HR line crosses through 1.

Comment: Ah, yes! My actual example used a binary covariate, so that wasn't necessary. Thanks!